# Проблемы со средой разработки Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Недавно появилась проблема со средой разработки PyCharm. Импортируемые модули подчеркиваются серым, а автокомплит при написании кода не работает(за исключением имен, используемых в коде). Все работало отлично, до того, как мне прилетело окно, что интерпретатор Python не выбран. После выбора одного из доступных начались данные проблемы, наносящие большой урон удобству при написании кода. В чем может заключаться проблема?

Comment: Ну наверное вы выбрали не тот интерпритатор. Например тот, в котором не установлены используемые вами библиотеки. Зайдите в настройки и выберете нужный или создайте новое виртуальной окружение.

Comment: Да, поменял пути, все заработало, спасибо большое)